# How to create an instance of org.gradle.api.file.Director

Tags: gradle, groovy, directory

I want to create an instance of [`org.gradle.api.file.Directory`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/Directory.html). From the Gradle docs I see that the only way to do this is to create the first instance using `project.getLayout().getProjectDirectory()` and then use the instance method `dir(<path>)` on this instance to create an instance for another directory.

Is there a way to directly create an instance of `Directory` class (like using a `File` object or directly using a string path)?

Comment: from [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/Directory.html): This interface is not intended for implementation by build script or plugin authors. so, why do you need it ?

Comment: @daggett The documentation wants to prevent build script and plugin authors from *implementing* the interface (as in `class MyDirectory implements Directory`). Instead they should create instances using the Gradle API to work with an internal implementation provided by Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

When I started working with the new Gradle [Lazy Configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html) API, I encountered the same problem. Even though `dir(<path>)` allows absolute paths and you may therefore construct a `Directory` instance for any directory, it appeared to me like bad design.

However, actually it is a pretty consistent design, because using the old API we just called `Project.file(...)` on our paths, which evaluated relative paths based on the project directory, too. Constructing `File` instances directly using its constructor was always a bad idea using Gradle. We may now just replace the calls to `file(<path>)` with calls to `layout.projectDirectory.dir(<path>)` or `.file(<path)` and get the same behavior.

Starting from version 6.0, Gradle also provides a method `dir(Provider<File>)` via its `ProjectLayout` class. You may construct the `Provider<File>` using the method `provider(Callable<>)` of the `Project` class, but whether this is actually useful depends on your specific use case.

Comment: This is insane. We just want to construct a class representing an absolute path to a directory. I've encountered it when wanting to configure [runIde.ideDir](https://lp.jetbrains.com/gradle-intellij-plugin/) when implementing an IntelliJ plugin. There is nothing relative to the Project path involved